# How to print unicode codepoint using printf

Tags: c, windows, unicode

I have been trying to print unicode string using printf. I looked through some of the other answers on setting locale and also setting console output on windows using SetConsoleOutputCP. However there is one problem that I couldn't find answer to.
Here is the code sample to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    printf("È\n");          // <-- This line prints È as expected
    printf("\u00C8\n");     // <-- This line does not print anything at all, not even a new line

    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in comment `printf("\u00C8\n");` does not print anything on windows but works perfectly on Linux. I would like know why and how can I have it print the appropriate unicode character.

Comment: What was the return values of `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")` ordinally and in your improved code?

Comment: This should not even compile because `#include <locale.h>` is missing. Moreover the result very much depends on the compiler and libraries you are using. "on Windows" holds about as much information as "in Europe".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica setLocale return the same string "en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: @n.m. Sorry about the missing header file. I'm not using any libraries though. I did not know it depended on the compiler as well. I should have mentioned it in the question itself but I'm using MSVC on windows and GCC on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UTF-8 encoding of the character `\u00C8` (Latin Capital Letter E with Grave) is `\xc3\x88`. So with a compiler that uses UTF-8, both `"È\n"` and `"\u00C8\n"` are equivalent to `"\xc3\x88\n"`.

If you use MSVC, then by default `"\u00C8\n"` does **not** produce a UTF-8 string. MSVC uses the *default codepage*. If you are working in say CP-1252, then the code for the character `\u00C8` happens to be `\xc8`, and this code is inserted in the string. It will obviously not work in the UTF-8 codepage. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ETW9evcWW).

You need to use `/utf-8` compiler switch to cause MSVC generate UTF-8 characters from universal character names. If you do, then "\u00C8\n" and `"È\n"` result in exactly the same string (provided your source file is UTF-8 encoded). [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xcG8qKz9P)